# Password manager autocomplete for a chrome extension

Tags: authentication, google-chrome-extension, password-manager

For the Chrome extension, the user has to type his password each time he log-in as the Chrome password manager is not working. (It works only for a website in the chrome browser)

The chrome extension is injecting a div in the page with the login form.  As the chromes extension is not tied to a domain, the Chrome password manager is not working.

How can we make a better UI for our users, so they dont have to type their password?

Comment: I am having the same issue and wondering if you ever solved this?

Comment: Nope.. I am thinking of implementing a LoginWith Google.